# Do both -だったら and -なら conditionals act as "topic marking" conditionals?

Tags: conditionals

In an [IMABI tutorial on conditionals](https://www.imabi.net/theconditionals.htm), the なら conditional is presented as something like a conditional topic marker:

> なら is called the contextual conditional because it is equivalent to "if you are talking about..., then...".

Later on, だったら is introduced as if it was a separate conditional:

> （の）だったら emphasizes a topic because of the condition of someone else.
>
> やりたくないんだったらやめてくれ。（Vulgar)
>
> ```
> If you don't want to do it, stop!
> ```
>
> お父さんだったら部屋にいるよ。
>
> ```
>  If you're talking about dad, he's in the room.
> ```

But this seems pretty much identical to the -なら conditional presented above, no? In both cases they are inheriting a topic from an external speaker/context, and are saying something like "well, speaking of X, then...".

Moreover, I've read elsewhere that -なら comes from an older form of the copula, meaning both of these conditionals are in some sense "copula conditionals".

**Overall Question:** Is there any difference in meaning between -なら and -だったら conditionals? Do they both mean something like "well if you're talking about..., then..."?

---

**EDIT:** A potential counter-example I found is

> もし私があなただったらすこし待つでしょう。
>
> If I were you, I'd wait a while.

Here だったら is being used in such a way that doesn't look like it's receiving a topic from an external conversation/context.  It seems wrong to translate (even literally) as

> Well, *speaking* of you, I'd wait a while.

no?